# Does it make sense to put all development works in Cloud?

Tags: development-environment, cloud

Is it possible having virtual machines in the cloud, install visual studio there, and making developers using the 'cloud' to do day-to-day programming work? Is the cost going to be too high? Is the speed going to be too slow?

Where can I find statistics or numbers to convince people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using remote virtual machines to run development servers, but I don't like using my IDE on a remote server. The latency is noticeable. If you're without an internet connection you can't work. My happy compromise is to have a dev server available (EC2) and sync it with my laptop via git.

Comment: I completely agree with this, also workstation hardware is so inexpensive now there's really no cost advantage to running an IDE in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely possible to do this, using a service like Rackspace you can set up a fairly powerful windows server for as little as $60 a month:

http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing

In my experience using Remote Desktop to log into a Rackspace Windows Cloud Server has been snappy and quick (of course a lot of that depends on the strength of your internet connection). The process of standing up the server is lighting fast, backing it up is even easier, and it can be easily resized down the line if you need more storage/bandwidth.

These days I don't understand why a small to mid sized organization would actually waste capital on server hardware.

Evan

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am actually more talking about the development workstations than development server. To make it clear, I am talking about having couple instances of windows 7, installing IDE there, having developers remote desktop into the server to do all the works. Will you recommend that?